# HttpListener vs HttpHandler dilemma

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, httplistener

In a Windows Service I implemented an HttpListener that will handle incoming HTTP Requests to a certain port, parse the query string, insert it in database and send a confirmation response. All works well and i was quite pleased with my solution. However, the clients said that they were a bit skeptical and asked if the same could have been done via a webpage. Like having an HTTPHandler listen to a certain port. Got me thinking. What would you do in my situation?

Go with the HttpListener/Windows Service or HTTPHandler/.aspx?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If nobody is going to be using the product with a web-UI, then there is absolutely, categorically, no point in exposing an ASP.NET site to the web - a service implies a demand of reliability, web-pages aren't _that_.

Comment: Yeah that is a valida argument and I'm going to bring that up in the meeting tomorrow. Could the same be done thru a Web Service tho?

Comment: Technically, yes, of course; but practically there is no point or benefit (that I know of) by hosting it in IIS unless is resides next to a accompanying website - just an extra set of records somewhere more apparent in the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you don't want to use a web server? We've implemented our own Http serving services because they are fairly unusual in the way they process the requests and would prove taxing on a normally configured IIS instance.

In your situation, this doesn't appear to be the case, so yes, I find myself wondering why you didn't go the webserver route either.

EDIT

Is there any other web facing part of your application? If not, I would concur that @Mr Disappoinment's reasoning is sound. You're only exposing what you need, which is considerably less attack surface than an IIS instance.

Comment: the win service i've imeplemented is merely an accompanying part to a web e-shop whereby people can buy e-newspapers subscriptions. I use the Windows Service to sync our database with our client's. I thought it would be a feasible option to install the windows services on our server, as well as on our client's server (the publishers). I don't see the benefits of using a webservice when I already have a working windows service who uses threading. I'm really insterested in your view since you have 15.4k reputation :)

Comment: I think that it's an implementation detail. If the solution is robust and works according to spec, there's no problem. Server techs tend to be reluctant to install software as a service because (they perceive that) it's harder to lock down/secure a bit of proprietary software than software running under IIS. From a dev's POV it's easier to constrain the running of a service and to keep memory under tighter control. At the end of the day, if you've delivered correctly, it's probably a chance to wring more work out of the deal if they are placing a late requirement on the type of delivery.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something through IIS, simply because I think my clients' IT staffs would require a pretty significant argument for me to be telling them to install custom services on their servers. I don't know enough about the threading behavior of the HttpListener (does it use thread pools? max number of threads? queueing once a max has been hit?) to say for sure, but I'd imagine that your client has similar concerns.

Comment: I get your point, but our clients just want to know the benefits of using a windows service over a .aspx or winservice. For starters I feel very comfortable working with the HttpListener class. Btw you are right about HttpListener using threadpools. That significantly decreases the overhead of the processor. Don't you think? Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it.

Comment: The point @joelt was making is that IIS provides you with finer control over how many processes and threads you want to dedicate to your web service, queuing requests, recycling etc.